# Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run

Tags: drush

I have a problem using drush. After typing command for enabling module I get an error:

Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'en devel' could not be executed.                  [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]

I have already tried to change host in settings.php localhost for 127.0.0.1 and also
php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '127.0.0.1' : 'localhost' and still does not work.Could anyone help me please? I am working on Vagrant on Ubuntu. Thanks

Here's the output of drush status:

```
Drush was attempting to connect to:
```

Drupal version        :  7.34
 Site URI              :  http://default
 Database driver       :  mysql
 Database username     :  root
 Database name         :  omega
 Default theme         :  garland
 Administration        :  garland
 theme
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                :  Linux
 Drush version         :  6.2.0
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :  /home/hegi/.drush/omega.alias.drushrc.php 
 Drupal root           :  /home/hegi/drubuntu-vagrant/docroot/omega 
 Site path             :  sites/default
 File directory path   :  sites/default/files

Comment: Please show us your drush command line and optionally the output of `drush status`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are runing drush from outside a drupal webroot folder. Ensure you are running drush from inside the folder where drupal is, anywhere within that folder drush should not give you this error.